# How to transfer from Fujifilm FinePix?

Tags: digital, fujifilm, usb

I have a Fujifilm FinePix AX550

How do I transfer the pictures to my computer ? The computer is a Linux laptop desktop running Debian. When I connect the camera to the computer, the camera acknowledges this by showing "USB" on the screen.

[image]

However I can't find any way to copy/transfer the pictures from the camera to the computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't see it as a plain mass storage device, it is possibly using the [MTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) or [PTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Transfer_Protocol) protocols. These are often supported at the application level by image/photo managers such as Gwenview, Digikam and perhaps GPhoto. Some cameras can also switch between mass storage and PTP (on my Lumix, this was done with Print mode).

The other solution is to take out the storage card and put it in a card reader(*). This makes it  behave as a mass storage and all your file managers will be able to read it (on my Ubuntu this appears in /media/{my_id}/{some_label}). This is also usually a lot faster (the USB link is slow).

(*) External but also built-in in many laptops these days.